# Setting and accessing properties of a PHP class object where the values have been retrieved from a DB within the class

Tags: php, class, oop

I've created a simple class that aims to retrieve details for staff members from a MySQL DB. Here is the class:

```
class staff {
    public function __construct($db, $id){
        $record = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM staff WHERE id = :id");
        $record->execute(array(':id' => $id));
        foreach($record as $k=>$v){
            $this->$k = $v;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the call:

```
$staffMember = new staff($db, $uid);
var_dump($staffMember);
```

And the var_dump gives this:

```
object(staff)#7 (1) {
  ["0"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["fname"]=>
    string(4) "Mike"
    [0]=>
    string(4) "Mike"
  }
}
```

So far so good, I can see things are retrieved and set. But I'm not happy about the implementation, two reasons:

1) It seems that values are duplicated, as I have two "Mike"'s in the array that is returned. Why is this happening and how do I prevent it?

2) Accessing the values is not straightforward, in the main PHP file I use something along the lines of:

```
$staffMember->{0}["fname"];
```

to retrieve the value of a staff members name. This doesn't look right, I expected to use $staffMember->fname. Is there another approach that will result in retrieved DB values being set as class/object variables rather than a single property that is actually an array and is rather cumbersome to access and probably even worse to manipulate?

My thanks in advance.

Comment: `$db` is a `PDO` instance?

Comment: you have the same result twice because you have the associative array (fname) and the numeric array (0); they are actually the same result, but because your request is ambiguous, both results are served.

Comment: Yes it is. Sorry I should have clarified that. $uid is the users id value set elsewhere on the page and corresponds to the record in the DB where the users name, DoB etc are held.

Comment: Take a look at [PDOStatement::fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) with `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` as `fetch_style`. That same page has some examples...

Comment: @Theavonguy I see. This is sorta my first serious attempt to use classes constructively, normally when I loop through a set of results from a query I believe that only the associative array is used, I'd forgotten that two sets are returned. I'll see what I can do to resolve that.

EDIT: Actually that resolves both issues. Thanks.

Comment: Personally, I'd define all required fields as instance members rather than creating them dynamically.

Comment: @simon So create a number of public variables in the class, and then rather than have the foreach loop dynamically creating vars you'd access each DB column and assign it to one of those public variables?

Comment: Basically yes, although I'd think about whether they really have to be public. It just feels more clear to me when I immediately can see what members a class has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($record as $k=>$v)
```

This iterates over **all rows** in the result set. The first row is `0` with several fields in `$v`. Further, you're using the default `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` fetch mode, which returns the data both numerically indexed and name associated.

If you just expect a single record to be returned, do this to loop over the columns of a single record *by name*:

```
foreach ($record->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $k => $v) {
    $this->$k = $v;
}
```

I would argue that setting public properties like this may not be ideal (tying database column names directly to public object API), but that's a different story...

Comment: Yes, this is the same as @Theavonguy 's comment above but thank you for the code example that's very helpful, will mark as the correct answer to help anyone coming across this.

Regarding setting public properties to have the same names as DB columns, since PHP is all server side how much does this expose you? Is there a better way to accomplish what I am looking to achieve?

Comment: It has nothing to do with exposing to the outside world. It has to do with separating concerns. You should model your database the best way you can model an RDBMS database. You should model your objects the best way you can model your objects. The two aren't and shouldn't necessarily correlate 1:1. There should be a "translation layer" between the RDBMS data structure and what you use internally in the form of an object. Think a record which is logically one thing but is actually stored across two tables in the database. Can make code *simpler* and gives you more flexibility in the long run.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying, your comments are about code clarity and usability?

Comment: Long term code maintenance and proper application architecture, yes.